# RStudio default workspace

Tags: r, rstudio

When I run Rstudio, some workspace that I saved long time ago appears.
What should I do if I want to start with a clean new workspace next time I run Rstudio?

Answer (score 3):

Under `options` in the `tools` menu, there is a checkbox `Restore .RData into workspace at startup`.  Uncheck this box and click `apply`.  That will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just click clear in the Environment tab.

Comment: In my version of rstudio, I think it's called "workspace", & you click a picture of a broom (nothing says "clear"). To do this w/ code, should you prefer, it is `rm(list=ls())`.

Comment: You must choose "Yes" to the popup "would you like to save this session?" appears when you are closing rstudio. Otherwise, the previously saved environment returns the next time rstudio is opened. That is: 1. open rstudio, 2. clear workspace, 3. click X to close rstudio, 4. click "yes" on save environment popup.